# Append transformed columns to spark dataframe using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I am trying to access a hive table and extract and transform certain columns from the table/dataframe and then put those new columns in a new dataframe.
I am trying to do it in this way -

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

val hiveDF = sqlContext.sql("select * from table_x")

val system_generated_id = hiveDF("unique_key")
val application_assigned_event_id = hiveDF("event_event_id")

val trnEventDf = sqlContext.emptyDataFrame
trnEventDf.withColumn("system_generated_id",lit(system_generated_id))
```

It builds without any error with sbt. But when I try to run it I receive the following error -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed
>       at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:221)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStar.expand(unresolved.scala:199)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:354)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$applyOrElse$14.apply(Analyzer.scala:353)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
>       at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
>       at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:353)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$10.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:347)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan$$anonfun$resolveOperators$1.apply(LogicalPlan.scala:57)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:69)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperators(LogicalPlan.scala:56)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:347)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.apply(Analyzer.scala:328)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:83)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>       at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:111)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:84)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:80)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:72)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:36)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:34)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.(DataFrame.scala:133)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.org$apache$spark$sql$DataFrame$$withPlan(DataFrame.scala:2126)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.select(DataFrame.scala:707)
>       at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn(DataFrame.scala:1188)
>       at bacon$.main(bacon.scala:31)
>       at bacon.main(bacon.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)

I would like to understand what causes this error and if there is any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you do not need to create a new df for this. When you transform the df by adding a unique Id to it, you get your desired df. If you would like to save it, simply save it as a new hive table.

Comment: Actually , its not only one column. I need to transform several columns and planned to create a new dataframe.The reason I wanted a new dataframe is because I planned to do 2 different sets of transformation on the dataframe in parallel using threads.

Comment: Don't . Each transformation is distributed by nature. Improve the transformations so they will distribute nicely and run fast instead.